# powershell scheduled task caller

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have several hundred scheduled tasks.  Im looking for a way to get the name of the task that called a powershell script when the script has been executed by the task scheduler.  So for instance I could include that name in an alert I am sending so we know not only which server but which specific task

Comment: Please provide som code that you've already tested as example to work with

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get-scheduledtask` cmdlet. You find this cmdlet in the `ScheduledTasks` module.

Each returned task has an Actions Property.

E.g.

```
(Get-ScheduledTask)[0].Actions
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Peter Schneider helpful answer which will give you details on the first task in the list. So, more specifically, to get them all, try this...

```
(((Get-ScheduledTask).Actions) | Select-Object *) -match 'powershell' | Select-Object -Property Id,Execute,Arguments | Format-Table -Wrap

Id                 Execute        Arguments
--                 -------        ---------
StartPowerShellJob powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Import-Module PSScheduledJob; …
```

Note, the '*' gest all properties and you may not want to do that, so, just explicitly select the ones you'd want

```
(((Get-ScheduledTask).Actions) | Select-Object -Property Id,Execute,Arguments) -match 'powershell' | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Answer (score 0):

To get notified when a task has finished running, you need som jobs that waits for each task to finish.

```
function Get-SchdTaskRunning {# Needs COM-object to expose PID
    $TaskService = New-Object -ComObject('Schedule.Service')
    $TaskService.Connect()

    return $TaskService.GetRunningTasks(1)
}

$RunningPosh = Get-ScheduledTask | where {
    $_.State -eq 'Running' -and
    $_.Actions.Execute -match 'powershell|pwsh'
}

#TODO Needs to be converted to an array using foreach to handle more than one PID
$RunningPoshPid = (Get-SchdTaskRunning | 
    where Path -eq ($RunningPosh[0].TaskPath + $RunningPosh[0].TaskName)
).EnginePid

#TODO Needs to be run as one job per Pid
Wait-Process -Id $PoshPid

Out-Host -InputObject (
    'Finished running: ' + 
    $RunningPosh.Actions.Arguments).split(' ')[0]
)
```

Note: Hadn't time to finish up...